# How do I make it so that when I put a vertex group with a hair particle system with an instance they don't go outside the box that I predefine?

Tags: modeling, hair, vertex-groups

How do I make it so that when I put a vertex group with a hair particle system with an instance they don't go outside the box that I predefine?

[image: The problem is here]

[image: EDIT 2 to show the vertex group and origin particle]

[image: Origin particle System]

[BLENDER](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gL95ukyOVIECpDGnz6pFDGGpIHAW8Bsf/view?usp=share_link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the origin of your particle object is correctly placed. As you see, the mesh is far from the origin, switch to *Edit* mode and move the mesh:

[image]

Comment: The origin is right, and vertex group is in a correct position, what does happen is that by making the texture that I use as hair smaller, it gets closer to the group that I made,

I edit the post to show about that

Comment: could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: yes i edit the post to share file

Comment: it looks like your problem is the one I pointed out

Comment: really thanks, i solve it and comment you